# How to better use .flatMap(), .map() and .filter() to iterate and filter through nested arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following data and I need to filter them and get the some info in a specific format:

```
const parentInfo = [
{
    childInfo: [
        {
            type: 'new',
            testOne: { subTestOne: '111' },
            testTwo: 'bbb',
            testThree: { subTestThree: '666' },
            testFour: 'ddd',
            testFive: 'eee',
        },
        {
            type: 'old',
            testOne: { subTestOne: '222' },
            testTwo: 'ggg',
            testThree: { subTestThree: '777' },
            testFour: 'iii',
            testFive: 'jjj',
        },
        {
            type: 'new',
            testOne: { subTestOne: '333' },
            testTwo: 'lll',
            testThree: { subTestThree: '888' },
            testFour: 'nnn',
            testFive: 'ooo',
        }
    ]
},
{
    childInfo: [
        {
            type: 'new',
            testOne: { subTestOne: '444' },
            testTwo: 'qqq',
            testThree: { subTestThree: '999' },
            testFour: 'sss',
            testFive: 'ttt',
        },
        {
            type: 'old',
            testOne: { subTestOne: '555' },
            testTwo: 'vvv',
            testThree: { subTestThree: '000' },
            testFour: 'xxx',
            testFive: 'yyy',
        }
    ]
},
]
```

I need the output to be:

```
{
   allOnes: ['111', '333', '444'],
   allTwos: ['bbb', 'lll', 'qqq'],
   allThrees: ['666', '888', '999'],
   allFours: ['ddd', 'nnn', 'sss'],
   allFives: ['eee', 'ooo', 'ttt']
}
```

I managed to get what I need with the following code but I think I am using more iterations than needed. I cannot find a way to make it simpler or at least more compact. Any suggestions?

```
 const getInfo = (parentInfo) => {

  const allOnes = parentInfo.flatMap(({
      childInfo
    }) =>
    childInfo
    .filter((childSingleInfo) => childSingleInfo.type === 'new')
    .map((childSingleInfo) => childSingleInfo.testOne.subTestOne),
  );

  const allTwos = parentInfo.flatMap(({
      childInfo
    }) =>
    childInfo
    .filter((childSingleInfo) => childSingleInfo.type === 'new')
    .map((childSingleInfo) => childSingleInfo.testTwo),
  );

  const allThrees = parentInfo.flatMap(({
      childInfo
    }) =>
    childInfo
    .filter((childSingleInfo) => childSingleInfo.type === 'new')
    .map((childSingleInfo) => childSingleInfo.testThree.subTestThree),
  );

  const allFours = parentInfo.flatMap(({
      childInfo
    }) =>
    childInfo
    .filter((childSingleInfo) => childSingleInfo.type === 'new')
    .map((childSingleInfo) => childSingleInfo.testFour),
  );

  const allFives = parentInfo.flatMap(({
      childInfo
    }) =>
    childInfo
    .filter((childSingleInfo) => childSingleInfo.type === 'new')
    .map((childSingleInfo) => childSingleInfo.testFive),
  );

  return {
      allOnes: allOnes.length
          ? Array.from(new Set(allOnes)).join(', ')
          : null,
      allTwos: allTwos.length
          ? Array.from(new Set(allTwos)).join(', ')
          : null,
      allThrees: allThrees.length
          ? Array.from(new Set(allThrees)).join(', ')
          : null,
      allFours: allFours.length
          ? Array.from(new Set(allFours)).join(', ')
          : null,
      allFives: allFives.length
          ? Array.from(new Set(allFives)).join(', ')
          : null,
    };
}
```

Here is a fiddle of my code: https://jsfiddle.net/rf6kL2s3/

I have updated the code to better reflect the actual data.

Comment: Combine the `childInfo`s, filter the `new` ones and then use `.reduce()` (+ `.replace()` for the property)

Comment: Have you ever thought about your data structure? Could that be changed ?

Comment: @iwaduarte Unfortunatelly it cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a dynmaic approach and replace the keys and check the type.

```js
const
    getKey = string => string.replace(/^test/, 'all'),
    getSubKey = string => 'sub' + string[0].toUpperCase() + string.slice(1),
    data = [{ childInfo: [{ type: 'new', testOne: { subTestOne: '111' }, testTwo: 'bbb', testThree: { subTestThree: '666' }, testFour: 'ddd', testFive: 'eee' }, { type: 'old', testOne: { subTestOne: '222' }, testTwo: 'ggg', testThree: { subTestThree: '777' }, testFour: 'iii', testFive: 'jjj' }, { type: 'new', testOne: { subTestOne: '333' }, testTwo: 'lll', testThree: { subTestThree: '888' }, testFour: 'nnn', testFive: 'ooo' }] }, { childInfo: [{ type: 'new', testOne: { subTestOne: '444' }, testTwo: 'qqq', testThree: { subTestThree: '999' }, testFour: 'sss', testFive: 'ttt' }, { type: 'old', testOne: { subTestOne: '555' }, testTwo: 'vvv', testThree: { subTestThree: '000' }, testFour: 'xxx', testFive: 'yyy' }] }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { childInfo }) => {
        childInfo.forEach(({ type, ...o }) => {
            if (type !== 'new') return;
            Object
                .entries(o)
                .forEach(([k, v]) => (r[getKey(k)] ??= [])
                    .push(v && typeof v === 'object' ? v[getSubKey(k)] : v))
        });
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The suggestion does the trick but I had an error in my initial code posted. I edited the question with more accurate data and I also updated the fiddle. I tried adgust your answer to the updated data unfortunately with no success.

Comment: @MavrosGatos, please see edit with a function for the subkey.

Comment: Works like a charm. I was wondering how would it work if the names of the initial data keys were completely different from each other. Same for the names of the result object keys. I cannot think of a way to compact my initial code at this level as your solution is based on the names of the keys. Correct?

Comment: for unknown names take `Object.values` and take the first or all values.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a map object, to keep relation between childInfo props and the resulting props, example allOnes: "testOne". With [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const parentInfo =  [{ childInfo: [{ type: 'new', testOne: 'aaa', testTwo: 'bbb', testThree: 'ccc', testFour: 'ddd', testFive: 'eee' }, { type: 'old', testOne: 'fff', testTwo: 'ggg', testThree: 'hhh', testFour: 'iii', testFive: 'jjj' }, { type: 'new', testOne: 'kkk', testTwo: 'lll', testThree: 'mmm', testFour: 'nnn', testFive: 'ooo' }] }, { childInfo: [{ type: 'new', testOne: 'ppp', testTwo: 'qqq', testThree: 'rrr', testFour: 'sss', testFive: 'ttt' }, { type: 'old', testOne: 'uuu', testTwo: 'vvv', testThree: 'www', testFour: 'xxx', testFive: 'yyy' }] }];

const maps = {allOnes: "testOne", allTwos: "testTwo",allThrees: "testThree",allFours: "testFour", allFives: "testFive"};

const result = parentInfo.reduce((res, current) => {
   const newElements = current.childInfo.filter(item => item.type === "new");
   Object.entries(maps).map(([key, value]) => {
     res[key] = [...res[key] || [], ...newElements.map(item => item[value])]
   })
  return res;
 }, {});


console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

After various tries I ended up with this solution that best fits my needs:

```
const getInfo = (parentInfo) => {
    const info = parentInfo.reduce(
      (acc, { childInfo }) => {
        childInfo
          .filter((child) => child.type === 'new')
          .forEach(({ testOne, testTwo, testThree, testFour, testFive }) => {
            acc.allOnes.push(testOne.subTestOne);
            acc.allTwos.push(testTwo);
            acc.allThrees.push(testThree.subTestThree);
            acc.allFours.push(testFour);
            acc.allFives.push(testFive);
          });
        return acc;
      },
      {
        allOnes: [],
        allTwos: [],
        allThrees: [],
        allFours: [],
        allFives: [],
      },
    );
    const finalInfo = {};
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(info)) {
      finalInfo[key] = Array.from(new Set(value)).join(', ');
    }
    return finalInfo;
};
```

Here is a fiddle of my code: https://jsfiddle.net/ezsbuvd3/